# Error in wins in coin flip program

Tags: java

For some reason my program is not printing the percentage you got right correctly. I don't know if I set it up wrong, but I am at a loss. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome. Its a simple program that tosses a coin where the user guesses if its head or tails and then it tells them if they won or not. The issue I am having is with counting the number of wins when the user wants to continue to play.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // This program asks the user to predict a toss of a coin.

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;
        String continuePlay = "";
        float count = 0;
        float wins =0;
        do{
        System.out.printf("Do you predict heads or tails for the coin toss: ");
        String prediction = in.next();


        System.out.print("Tossing the coin");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        System.out.print(".");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        System.out.print(".");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        System.out.print(".");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        System.out.println(".");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);


        Random rand = new Random();
        int toss = Math.abs(rand.nextInt()) % 2;
        if(toss == 0){
            System.out.print("It came up heads.");

        }else{
            System.out.print("It came up tails.");

        }
        if(prediction.equals("h") && toss==0){
            System.out.print(" You win.");
            wins ++;
        }else if(prediction.equals("h") && toss !=0){
            System.out.print(" You loose.");
        }else if(prediction.equals("t") && toss==1){
            System.out.print(" You win.");
            wins ++;
        }else if(prediction.equals("t") && toss!=1){
            System.out.print(" You loose.");
        }


        // Ask user if they want to continue to play
        System.out.print("\nDo you want to play again? (\"c\" to continue \"q\" to quit): ");
        continuePlay = in.next();
        if (continuePlay.equals("c")){
            done = false;
        } else done = true;

        count ++;



        }while(done == false);


        double percentWon = (wins / count) * 100;

        System.out.printf("Thanks for playing. You guessed my number %.0f%% of the time.\n", percentWon);
            in.close();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the error is in your win increment... I think that every time you get a win, you reset the win count to 1... in here

```
 }
        if(prediction.equals("h") && toss==0){
            System.out.print(" You win.");
            wins =1;
        }else if(prediction.equals("h") && toss !=0){
            System.out.print(" You loose.");
        }else if(prediction.equals("t") && toss==1){
            System.out.print(" You win.");
            wins=1;
        }else if(prediction.equals("t") && toss!=1){
            System.out.print(" You loose.");
        }
```

try changing to...

```
 }
        if(prediction.equals("h") && toss==0){
            System.out.print(" You win.");
            wins ++;
        }else if(prediction.equals("h") && toss !=0){
            System.out.print(" You loose.");
        }else if(prediction.equals("t") && toss==1){
            System.out.print(" You win.");
            wins++;
        }else if(prediction.equals("t") && toss!=1){
            System.out.print(" You loose.");
        }
```

and take the win++; in the end out.

Comment: No that was not it. I tried two games where i won once and lost the other and it printed i won 0% of the time. It should be printing you won 50% of the time.

Comment: change the int variables to float also, because in int, 0,5 is 0... I didn't test your code, just my presumption

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer and debug your code! ;D